# Printing binary search tree nodes using inorder traversal (recursion) in Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

I am trying to implement a simple inorder traversal method on a binary search tree.

```
            10
          /    \
         5      15
          \
           8
```

I want to print the whole tree but I am only getting the first 3 nodes printed. My questions are:

-- How can I fix my 'inorder' print method? 'insert' method works fine.
-- What is the base condition in the inorder method? How will it know to stop when all the nodes have been printed?

```
 class Tree:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.node = value
    self.leftChild = None
    self.rightChild  = None

  def insert(self, value):
    if self.node is None:
        self.node = value
        return True
    if self.node is not value:
        if self.node > value:
            if self.leftChild  is None:
                self.leftChild  = Tree(value)
            else:
                return self.leftChild.insert(value)
        if self.node < value:
            if self.rightChild  is None:
                self.rightChild  = Tree(value)
            else:
                 return self.rightChild.insert(value)
    else:
        return False

  def inorder(self):
      if self:  
          if self.leftChild:
              return self.leftChild.inorder()
          print self.node
          if self.rightChild:
              return self.rightChild.inorder()


tree = Tree(10)
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(15)
tree.inorder()


> 5
  8
  10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` in `return self.leftChild.inorder()` ends the call to `inorder` before `self` and `self.rightChild` can be handled. Remove the `return`s, the method doesn't return anything anyway.

Comment: Many thanks! That was it! About my base condition question, I am getting really lost with these recursions.  Let me ask this way:  suppose our tree has the following only 4 nodes: Root is 10:  10’s Left Child is 5: 10’s Right Child is 15:  5’s Right Child is 8. Inorder()  will start with the Root and call self.leftChild.inorder(), which is ‘5’. Now node ‘5’ will call self.leftChild.inorder() again, but since it has no left child would execute ‘print self.node’. Next, it will call self.rightChild.inorder() which will lead it to 8. Since 8 has no right child it will execute ‘print self.node’.

Comment: Questions: From node 8, how does inorder() know that it should go all the way back to 10? And how will it know when all the nodes have been visited?

Comment: "node ‘5’ will call self.leftChild.inorder()" no, `if self.leftChild` means it won't even try that. And btw `if self` is pointless, remove that. To your questions: recursion isn't magic, it's just function calls. When one function call finishes, the function that called it continues where it left off. Python keeps track of all function calls in frames in a stack. I suggest stepping through a debugger. [Here's a simple one](http://www.pythontutor.com/). It doesn't know how to do anything you're not seeing or aren't already familiar with. It's just doing what you told it to.

Comment: Your comment and the awesome debugger link that you've shared cleared many of my doubts! Thank you!